About Jesus's reading of Isaiah in the synagogue
Luke 4:18 reads:  "The Spirit of the LORD is upon Me, Because He has anointed Me To preach the gospel to the poor; He has sent Me to heal the brokenhearted, To proclaim liberty to the captives And recovery of sight to the blind, To set at liberty those who are oppressed;
However the passage in Isaiah 61:1 does not mention recovery of sight...did Jesus add this?

It is likely that this question is answered in the book "Commentary on the New Testament Use of the Old Testament". See here: https://www.amazon.com/Commentary-New-Testament-Use-Old/dp/0801026938

Jesus and the New Testament writers employed various styles of citation, everything from a word for word quote to a paraphrase to an elaboration. Sometimes they will combine the words of several prophets but only cite the name of one of the sources, just like we will give the lead author on a book but leave off the co-authors for brevity.
"Commentary on the New Testament Use of the Old Testament" edited by D. A. Carson and G. K. Beale goes into the contemporary rabbinic traditions around quoting scripture that would have been in fashion back then.
There is a section in the above book on Luke 4:18-19. the authors say that Jesus is drawing from themes from throughout Isaiah, not just the obvious passage. Thus the part about giving sight to the blind is a reference to Isaiah 42:7:

to open the eyes that are blind, to bring out the prisoners from the
dungeon,
from the prison those who sit in darkness.

